# Finding the exact overlapping time

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with tickets as (
    select o.SSTID, o.open_Id, o.Createddatetime openTime, c.Createddatetime closeTime 
    from dbo.Close_ticket  c
    inner join dbo.Openticket o ON o.SSTID = c.SSTID and c.Open_ID=o.open_id
    
)
select t1.SSTID,
   SUM(isnull(datediff(hour
    , case when t1.openTime > t2.openTime then t1.openTime else t2.openTime end
    , case when t1.closeTime > t2.closeTime then t2.closeTime else t1.closeTime end),0)) as [OverLappingtime] 
   
from tickets t1 

left join tickets t2 on t1.SSTID = t2.SSTID
    and t1.openTime < t2.closeTime and t2.openTime < t1.closeTime 
    and t1.open_id < t2.open_id 
    group by t1.SSTID
```

This is my code where each ticket is compared to every other ticket to find the total overlapping time. But if I create more tickets the total time exceeds 24 hours when all the tickets where created on the same day. How can I find the exact overlapping time? **If we see the first three tickets, the 2nd and the third ticket were opened and closed within the opening and closing time of the first ticket.

I need the exact overlapping time.**

This is my Openticket table.

```
[Open_ID,SSTID,Createddatetime]

 - 1,1,2020-04-27 06:40:32.337
 - 2,1,2020-04-27 12:40:32.337
 - 3,1,2020-04-27 14:40:32.337
 - 4,1,2020-04-27 15:40:32.337
 - 5,1,2020-04-27 18:40:32.337
```

This is my Close_ticket table.

```
[Close_id,open_id,SSTID,Createddatetime]

 - 1,1,1,2020-04-27 20:40:32.337
 - 2,2,1,2020-04-27 15:40:32.337
 - 3,3,1,2020-04-27 16:40:32.337
 - 4,4,1,2020-04-27 17:40:32.337
 - 5,5,1,2020-04-27 21:40:32.337
```

Comment: Your question is missing your expected output from your example data, which would clarify what you're asking. I'm not clear what you mean by "exact overlapping time".

Comment: @user9601310 by exact overlapping time, consider the first three tickets, its overlapping time should be 4 hours because the 2nd and the 3rd ticket were opened and closed within the time range of the first ticket. But according to my code the output is 6hours of the first three tickets.

Comment: Hi - taking the 1st record as the "driver" for the query, the 2nd record is completely with the duration of the 1st and has a duration of 3; the 3rd record is completely with the duration of the 1st and has a duration of 2; the 4th record is completely with the duration of the 1st and has a duration of 2; the 5th record partially overlaps the 1st, has a duration of 3 but an overlap of 2. Total overlap = 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 9 - so where are you getting 4 as the overlap?. 2 and 3 also overlap each other. Please provide the logic that you want to use to calculate overlap

Comment: @NickW the 4hrs I mentioned were of the first three tickets. The logic I mentioned above is the one I'm using. But using that, I get the overlapping time as 6(considering the first three tickets only) but the actual overlapping time should be 4 hours.

Comment: The overlap for the first 3 tickets appears to be 5 (3+2) not 4. This is why I asked you to provide the logic you were using rather than just stating numbers. Please can you list the steps you are following in order to get to 4 hours - as what might seem obvious to you is not necessarily obvious to people trying to help you.

Comment: Also - are you looking for the overlap time for each record i.e. take each record and find any records that fully or partially overlap with it - so the overlap can potentially be counted multiple times across different "lead" records? What happens if, when looking at record A, it is overlapped by B & C but C also overlaps B - do you count both the A/B and A/C overlaps (which double counts some of the overlap) or do you also have to remove the B/C overlap?

Comment: remove the b/c overlap @NickW

Comment: Hi - we still need the logic you are using to calculate the overlap if you want someone to help you (see my comment Nov 9 at 14:10)

Comment: @NickW the logic I've used so far is the one I mentioned. I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You keep saying "the logic I've used so far is the one I mentioned" but at no point have you actually mentioned this logic in any useful form so that anyone can understand what it is you are doing: all you are doing is stating numbers with no indication on how you calculated these numbers.

Please provide a step by step guide to show how you calculated an overlap figure of 4 hours for the first 3 tickets.
For example, taking your data but moving the start/end times to the hour (rather than 40:32.337) for the sale of simplicity, we have this:
[image]

Possible overlap calculations:

1. 2 overlaps 1 by 3 hours => overlap is 3
2. 3 overlaps 1 by 3 hours => overlap is 3
3. You want to calculate overlap of both 2 & 3 compared to 1: 3 + 3 = 6
4. You only want the overlap when all 3 tickets overlap: 1
5. You don't want to double count any overlap: 2 overlaps 1 by 3 hours, 3 overlaps 1 by 3 hours, 2 & 3 overlap each other by 1 hour (double count) => 3 + 3 - 1 = 4

So which of these possible calculations are you using or are you using completely different logic and, if so, what it that logic?

Comment: the 5th point you mentioned is correct. I do not want any double overlaps.